# Change Image in a form when the image is selected in another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I decided to make a card game to help me learn how to program in C# using Visual Studio 2010.

**My Goal**: 
I want to be able:

1. to change the image on the back of the card deck (`dealButton`) on one form (`cardTableForm`)
2. to match the image in a picture box (`blackCheckerDeck`) on a different form (optionsForm) when I click the picture box in the `optionsForm`.

**My Code**:

```
 //Changes the deck design to blackChecker when the blackChecker design is selected.
 private void blackCheckerDeck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       cardTableForm.dealButton.Image = this.blackCheckerDeck.Image;
   }
```

**My Problem**:

The part of the last line that reads "`cardTableForm.dealButton`" has the following error

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.cardTableForm.dealButton'
```

Based on advise from this site I've already changed the properties of (`dealButton`) and (`blackCheckerDeck`) to

```
Modifiers: Public
```

Answer (score 0):

`cardTableForm` is a class.  You need to use an instance (object) to modify the deal button image.

When you create the Option form, you will need to give it the instance of the `cardTableForm`.

So assuming you have something like this in `cardTableForm`

```
void OnShowOptions()
{
   var options = new OptionsForm();
   options.CardTable = this;  // tell options which card form to play with
   ...
}
```

in OptionsForm

```
public CardTableForm CardTable;

void blackCheckerDeck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CardTable.dealButton.Image = this.blackCheckerDeck.Image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

  CardTable.dealButton.Image = this.blackCheckerDeck.Image;

  When I debug the above is giving me NullReferenceException was unhandled Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: (dealButton) is already set to the Image (dealDeck). (blackCheckerDeck) is replacing that image.